# Boost serialization throws std exception

Tags: c++, boost, boost-serialization

While testing some code that uses the Boost serializer I saw that a std::length_error was thrown while de-serializing. I run the code below on Linux (on Windows I did not see this issue). I am using Boost 1.47.0.

My serialization class:

```
class TestClass
{
public:
    TestClass() {};

    TestClass(const char* string1, const char* string2, const char* string3):
        string1(string1),
        string2(string2),
        string3(string3)
    {};

    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive & archive, const unsigned int version)
    {
        // When the class Archive corresponds to an output archive, the
        // & operator is defined similar to <<.  Likewise, when the class Archive
        // is a type of input archive the & operator is defined similar to >>.
        archive & this->string1;
        archive & this->string2;
        archive & this->string3;
    }

    std::string string1;
    std::string string2;
    std::string string3;
};
```

My test code:

```
TestClass testClass;
std::string value("nonsense");
try
{
    std::stringstream stringStream;
    stringStream << value;
    boost::archive::text_iarchive serializer(stringStream);
    serializer >> testClass;
}
catch (const boost::archive::archive_exception& e)
{
    ....
}
```

When executing this code I get an std::length_error:

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::length_error'
>   what():  basic_string::resize

Is this known (documented) behaviour of the Boost serializer, can I do a check on the input stream to see if it is valid or is there a try/catch missing in the deserialiser?

Regards,
    Johan

Comment: `string::resize` will throw `length_error` only when someone is trying to make `size()` larger than `max_size()`. This is almost impossible unless the platform has limited the allocation size.

Comment: I think because text_archive has almost no structure most of the errors will be of this kind and not archive_exception's, maybe if you use other archive type, like xml the archive_exception will be raised. The solution is to catch a parent standard exception and depending on the application to rethrow whatever exception is more informative to your program.

Comment: @alfC: I was hoping (and actually expecting) that these exceptions would have been caught by the archiver. I was catching the archive_exception but not the std exceptions. I now added the std::excpetion to the catch and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

You are writing a string and reading your TestClass.

Your line

```
archive & this->string2;
```

does already try to read from uninitialized memory. This means, it is likely that you try to allocate a std::string with a too large size (50% of the times, with two strings very like likely every time).

Thus, the exception comes from your code and it is not surprising that is is not caught from the archiver.